# How can I remove this child image Flash / AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, removechild

Following tutorials I managed to cobble the following together that imports an image from an external XML file.

But how do I remove it?

I've read up on removeChild but it looks like it needs to have a ref passed to it and I'm not sure what that ref is. I've tried a few things that I thought it might be, including (image) but all of them throw up **Access of undefined property** errors.

This is the code I'm using to import :

```
var imgrequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(artwork);
var loader:Loader = new Loader();   

    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, on_loadComplete);

    function on_loadComplete(e:Event):void {
        var image:DisplayObject = loader.content;       
            image.x = 0;
            image.y = 4;
            image.width = 150;
            image.height = 150;
        addChild(image);      
        Bitmap(image).smoothing = true;
    }
    loader.load(imgrequest);
```

What do I need to do to remove it?

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a variable inside a set of curly brackets, that variable only exists within those brackets. So when you try to remove the image (which DOES still exist outside the curly brackets) using that variable... no dice.

So you need to find a way to store that image with a method that results in a more permanently accessible object such as a global variable or putting it in an array (which is likewise stored globally).  Now you can do

```
image.parent.removeChild(image);
```

or if it's in an array

```
array[ind].parent.removeChild(array[ind]);
```

where `ind` is the index of that array element you want to remove.

Answer (score 0):

After using `addChild(image);` does later on using `removeChild(image);` not work?

Also try declaring `var image:DisplayObject;` outside of any functions (now can be universal to all functions) then in your `on_loadComplete` the first line can simply be `image = loader.content;`.
 Also *removeChild* will understand `image` when it's used later in another function.

Comment: That akward moment when you finally answer a tab that was open for ages... If the older answer (by @NealDavies) works then please mark his one as correct.